# WSO2 IS cannot add new profile from User Profile Management

Tags: wso2

When I go to "My Identity -> My Profiles", it does not give me the option to Add New Profile (as seen on the documentation for User Profile Management), but I can only edit the default profile.

I am using an external MySQL server as the JDBC user store, and creation and editing of users works fine.

I did not find any parameter in the xml files to enable this multiple profile feature. How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: The closer I got to having multiple profiles was using the addUser service to create a new user with profileName other than 'default'. Then that user is given a default profile and the other profile, but still I cannot add newer ones (GUI doesnt give me the Add New Profile choice yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I also find the same. Adding multiple profile for user has been removed from UI. But with JDBC user store,  I guess, we can add this using the web service API. Following is the API

https://{ip}:{port}/services/UserProfileMgtService?wsdl

Comment: Thanks. It's not a big deal, but the documentation (IS-4.5.0) is confusing, it doesn't tell the same story.